# Componentes personalizados

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

Há alguma maneira de criar componentes/telas personalizados com alguns componentes já carregados? Como por exemplo, criar uma `UIViewController` customizada, com alguns elementos padrão nela. **Mas de maneira que fique adicionável através do `StoryBoard`.**

**Situação de exemplo:**

Criar uma `UIViewController` customizada, com dois `UIButton` e uma `UIImageView` padrão nela. De modo que eu possa adicionar esta controladora customizada via `StoryBoard`.

Comment: Gostaria de saber também, em minhas pesquisas criar componentes e inseri-los na palheta de componentes padrão não é possível, sempre que preciso de algum componente de terceiro eu crio um cocoapods e coloco as library's que preciso

Comment: Você pode estender a classe `UIViewController` e criar os elementos via código ou no storyboard adicionar os elementos e apenas linkar os `IBOutlets` para que o funcionamento sirva para todas as telas que usarem essa classe

Answer (score 1):

Gian, veja se isto pode lhe ajudar https://www.weheartswift.com/make-awesome-ui-components-ios-8-using-swift-xcode-6/

PS: não consigo colocar como comentário